# Am I using python's apply_async correctly?

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

This is my first time trying to use multiprocessing in Python. I'm trying to parallelize my function `fun` over my dataframe `df` by row. The callback function is just to append results to an empty list that I'll sort through later.

Is this the correct way to use `apply_async`? Thanks so much.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

function_results = []
async_results = []

p = mp.Pool() # by default should use number of processors

for row in df.iterrows():
    r = p.apply_async(fun, (row,), callback=function_results.extend)
    async_results.append(r)

for r in async_results:
    r.wait()

p.close()
p.join()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like using [map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map) or [imap_unordered](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.imap_unordered) (dependending on whether you need your results to be ordered or not) would better suit your needs

```
import multiprocessing as mp

#prepare stuff

if __name__=="__main__":

    p = mp.Pool()

    function_results = list(p.imap_unorderd(fun,df.iterrows())) #unordered
    #function_results = p.map(fun,df.iterrows()) #ordered

    p.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - any particular reason why `map` or `imap` is better?

Comment: There might be a difference in speed but i have not tested that. imap and imap_unordered return their first results faster and you do not need to have the complete output in memory at once - which can be interesting if you are just going to iterate over it.